# How does your terraform pipeline look like with trunk based development?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terragrunt

I was brainstorming the other day with a colleague, on how you should deploy to multiple AWS accounts by making use of trunk based development (feature/ -> master).

The idea of deploying to multiple environments from master was bugging us, because how to determine when and where to deploy to?

I would love to see some thoughts and ideas on how some of you tackle this.

e.g. you have 1 master branch, and 3 separate aws accounts for (dev, staging and prod).

Answer (score 2):

I've thought about this a lot.

Using a trunk based development flow where we assume the infra is in alignment with infra-as-code (i.e. code reflects the state of the environment), I've found the simplest/clearest method is to have a different directory for each of the environments in combination with modules.

some-module v1.2.0

```sh
├── datalake (a component)
│   ├── dev (a terraform working directory) (some resources, also references some-module v1.2.0
│   └── prod (a terraform working directory) (some resources, also references some-module v1.1.0)
└── networks (a component)
    ├── dev (a terraform working directory)
    └── prod (a terraform working directory)
```

Once merged, you should auto-apply changes. If you're worried, implement a check to avoid destroy and recreates but this should always show in your spec plans as part of CI before approval anyway.

By having this pattern and using a "what doesn't work gets reverted" approach. You can ensure that new implementations work in dev before you copy them to prod.

Some common alternative views would be:

- splitting via a `../common` directory:

  - Pro: Good for avoiding drift
  - Con: Terrible for rapid iteration in dev.
- Splitting via TFvars:

  - Pro: Simple and consistent environments are identical except for a few values (inputs not resources), similar to common modules dir.
  - Con: Doesn't allow for drift (of resources) without affecting all environments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jake, the only thing that would still bother me is code duplication among the dev and prod folders. 

I was initially thinking of master branch containing 1 set of code, that's deployed among the different environments and uses tfvars to inject variables per environment.

I like your approach and I'll keep it in mind, thanks!

Comment: Tfvars can work well if you're okay with resource changes changing all environments at the same time. Otherwise you'd want a manual gate of some kind to deploy to production. Good luck, mate.